# Jboss/Wildfly SSL with Windows-My or Windows-ROOT certificates

Tags: ssl, jboss, wildfly

How to configure Wildfly/jboss (10.0.0) SSL with a cert installed in windows-my keystore.

Thanks in advance

Comment: which functionality do you want with SSL configuration? your jboss login or your application url ? Also what is the version of JBoss/wildfly?

Comment: @Abhijeet our application url and wildfly 10 final we are using

Answer (score 0):

I have created my own library to access windows certificate store, based on the git repo here https://github.com/agrawald/java-win-cred-store.

As per my research JBOSS 7.3 does not support windows certificate store access via standalone.xml.

Answer (score -1):

You have to configure connectors from **web** subsystem of your jboss/wildfly server.

You can replace the https connector with the following configuration in your `domain.xml/standalone.xml` file.

```
<connector name=”https” protocol=”HTTP/1.1” scheme=”https” socket-binding=”https” secure=”true”>
     <ssl key-alias=”privatekey” password=”password” certificate-key-file=”path_to_certificate_key_file” verify-client=”want” ca-certificate-file=”path_to_ca_certficate_file” ca-certificate-password=”password” truststore-type=”JKS”/>
</connector>
```

After adding the above configuration, restart your server and try to access https URL. you will be prompt for providing a certificate.

> Update

According to comment, You are using legacy security so you can use following cli command to add **One-Way SSL**

```
/core-service=management/security-realm=UndertowRealm/server-identity=ssl:add(keystore-path="server.keystore", keystore-relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir", keystore-password="secret")
```

Finally, set the value of Undertow's https listener to your Security Realm:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=default-https:write-attribute(name=security-realm,value=UndertowRealm)
```

Note: you need to create `UndertowRealm` mention above commands first

Comment: We want to use windows cert store path, May be some thing like this,
`<security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
                <server-identities>
                    <ssl>
                          <keystore provider="Windows-MY" keystore-password="password" alias="XXXX"/>   
                    </ssl>
                </server-identities>`                                                                                                                        But this is not working. Anyone tried this??

Comment: Does anyone had luck using Windows Certificate Store with JBOSS.